# Check if JSON value exists - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview, try-catch

I have an iOS application which downloads and parses a Twitter JSON feed and then presents that feed in a UITableView. This all works fine but I have one question:

When the user taps a UITableView cell, the app will look into the array "tweets_links" and see if that particular tweet has an attached URL, if it does then the web view will appear.

Because not all tweets have website URLs, I have added a simple try catch statement (like in C++) which can tell me if there is an exception when trying to access that part of the array.

My question is: is this is good or bad approach to doing this??

Here is my code:

```
int storyIndex = indexPath.row;
int url_test = 1;
NSString *url;

@try {
    url = [[tweets_links[storyIndex] valueForKey:@"url"] objectAtIndex:0];
}

@catch (NSException *problem) {
    // There is NO URL to access for this Tweet. Therefore we get the out of bounds error.
    // We will NOT take the user to the web browser page.
    // Uncomment the line below if you wish to see the out of bounds exception.
    // NSLog(@"%@", problem);
    url_test = 0;
}

if (url_test == 1) {
    WebBrowser *screen = [[WebBrowser alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    self.seconddata = screen;
    seconddata.web_url = url;
    screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentViewController:screen animated:YES completion:nil];
}

else if (url_test == 0) {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Info" message:@"There is no URL attatched to this Tweet." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];

    [tweetTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Is there a much better way of trying to achieve what I am doing???

Thanks, Dan.

Comment: There should be no need for try-catch.  When you ask an NSDictionary for a non-existent entry, it returns `nil`, which you can easily test for.  (In fact, you'd have to try pretty hard to get an exception.)

Comment: And don't use `valueForKey:`, use `objectForKey:`.

Comment: Because valueForKey: is a highly complex method that can handle all kinds of key paths for all kinds of different objects, so it has to carefully examine what the path is, what kind of object the method is sent to, and so on, while objectForKey is just for looking up things in a dictionary. Probably runs ten times faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using try and catch is Objective-C isn't encouraged there are other ways checking and handling errors

```
// firstObject will return the first object in the array or nil if the array is empty.
url = [[tweets_links[storyIndex][@"url"]] firstObject];

if (!url) {
    // handle the case for no url
} else {
    // do something with url
}
```

Since sending a message to `nil` is safe in Objective-C and returns `nil` it's safe to chain calls. e.g. If the dictionary didn't have an object for that key, then it would return `nil` and sending `firstObject` to `nil` returns `nil`.

Comment: It's not wise to chain calls when you don't quite know what you're doing.  Makes debugging much harder.

Comment: @HotLicks That is very true. However, if you're dealing with JSON responses that may or may not contain data, and you can sensibly deal with that data not existing, then it's __arguably__ easier to just try it and deal with nil responses. Something I learned from Haskell and the `Maybe` monad.

Comment: But for a novice especially, a long chain of calls is confusing and hard to pick apart, so comprehension is lost.  There is no harm in breaking down the chain -- no performance is lost, no function is lost.

Comment: @hotlicks. I agree. But not everyone wants a novice level answer.

Comment: But I've been programming for 40 years, and I don't like long chains either.  Too hard to understand and debug.

Answer (score 1):

Using either if the below approaches will be fine because TRY CATCH is used to catch programming errors
and use
**objectForKey:**
 instead of
**valueForKey**:

```
if ([tweets_links[storyIndex] objectForKey:@"url"] != nil)
```

OR

```
if ([url isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
{
// Code handling the URL
}
else
{
// Code handling there is no URL
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a ton about the Twitter feed, but you can probably check for a `nil` value returned from `objectForKey:` like so

```
if ([tweets_links[storyIndex] objectForKey:@"url"] != nil) { /* process the URL */ }
```

Your code assumes that the value is always an array of at least size = 1, it would be safer to inspect the @"url" key's value before assuming it's an array.

Answer (score 0):

Using exceptions in Objective-C is throwned upon. Exceptions are reserved for programming errors. You don't catch them, you fix the code. With a JSON document, you never have any guarantees what you received, so just be careful.

```
NSString* url = nil;
NSArray* linksArray = nil;
NSDictionary* linkDict = nil;
NSArray* urlArray = nil;

if ([tweet_links isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
    linksArray = tweet_links;

if (storyIndex >= 0 && storyIndex < linksArray.count)
    linkDict = linksArray [storyIndex];

urlArray = linkDict [@"url"];
if ([urlArray isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] && urlArray.count > 0)
    url = urlArray [0];

if ([url isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
{
    // Code handling the URL
}
else
{
    // Code handling there is no URL
}
```

Note that sending messages to a nil object always returns 0 / NO / nil as appropriate.

And please get into the habit of naming variables properly. You wrote "int url_test = 1;". What does url_test mean? I read the variable name, I have no idea what it means. I need to understand all the code. Making it "int" means it could be 0, 1, 2, 20000 or whatever. If you write instead "BOOL urlValid = YES;" that is clear: It means that you have a valid URL.

Answer (score 0):

Since url value is a NSString value, you could use `length` to check both if it's nil and if not, if it has any value (not empty string). You can check then if this NSString is a valid url.

```
  - (BOOL) validateUrl: (NSString *) candidate {
        NSString *urlRegEx = @"(http|https)://((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*)+([\\.|/]((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*))+";
        NSPredicate *urlTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx]; 
        return [urlTest evaluateWithObject:candidate];
    }
```

....

```
NSString *url = [[tweets_links[storyIndex][@"url"]] firstObject];

if ([url length] && [self validateUrl: url]) {
 // Has a valid URL
}
```

Comment: non empty strings are not valid urls. It's probably better to just try and use the URL and deal with any errors then rather than taking this simplistic approach.

Comment: Well, in that case you can use a validate method to check the url string. See edited answer! :)